# How to rebind RACSignal to BOOL variable?

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have a tree-based data structure with Node as its base class:

```
@interface Node : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) Node *parentNode;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL detached;
@end
```

When *detached* variable of parent's node is equal to YES, then the same property of the child should become YES. This behaviour modelled with the following code:

```
@implementation Node

- (void)setParentNode:(Node *)parentNode {
    _parentNode = parentNode;
    RAC(self, detached) = [RACObserve(_parentNode, detached) filter:^BOOL(id value) {
        return [value boolValue];
    }];
}

@end
```

How can I rebind *detached* property when parent is being changed? If do nothing there will be a crash in that case:

```
Node *node = [Node new];
Node *parentNode = [Node new];
Node *grandparentNode = [Node new];
parentNode.parentNode = grandparentNode;
node.parentNode = parentNode;
[RACObserve(node, detached) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"node.detached: %@", x);
}];
Node *newParent = [Node new];
node.parentNode = newParent;
grandparentNode.detached = YES;
```

I have found the discussion [here](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/419) but I can not realize how to adopt solution their to my case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, avoid constructing signals within setters. It's unnecessarily imperative, and RAC offers many more declarative ways to express *what* you're trying to do (instead of *how* to do it).

So, instead of putting anything into `-setParentNode:`, you can bind to your own property at initialization time (for example):

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self == nil) return nil;

    // Use @NO instead if that makes more sense as a default.
    RAC(self, detached, @YES) = [RACObserve(self, parentNode.detached) filter:^(NSNumber *detached) {
        return [detached boolValue];
    }];

    return self;
}
```

This will update `self.detached` whenever `self.parentNode` or `self.parentNode.detached` changes. If `self.parentNode` is `nil`, the property will default to `YES`.